# sqLite ON DELETE CASCADE not working on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, mobile

I have those two tables level and translation. In the level table there is an foreign key constraint to translation. The sql statement looks like this

```
Translation table:
CREATE TABLE Translation(idTranslation INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, de TEXT NOT NULL,frTEXT NOT NULL);

Level table:
CREATE TABLE Level (idLevel INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fkTranslation INTEGER NOT NULL, status INTEGER NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY (fkTranslation) REFERENCES Translation ( idTranslation ) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

But now when Im trying to delete an entry fron level the corresponding translation entry is not deleted!

And no, I havent forgot to put the

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
```

on the onOpen().

Also right before the delete command I checked with

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys;");
```

if its returned on and it returned 1, so its active.

Has anyone an idea what I can test or where I did the mistake? I already tested so much stuff that I don't no longer know where the error could be.

Thank you already in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cascade is used to prevent the database from throwing a referential constraint error when trying to remove a record that is being referenced thorugh a foreign key constraint.

In your case, deleting a level record will not create such a situation. It will simply remove a referencing record, but will not remove a record that is being referenced.

It works the other way around. If you delete a translation record, the corresponding level record will cascade, i.e. be deleted, because otherwise, it will have a reference to a translation record that no longer exist.

It would make little sense if it would work like you expect it to work. For example, let's say I have a Customer table and an Order table. The order must reference a customer. If the customer is deleted, it makes sense to delete the orders as well, because I cannot have orders that don't reference a customer. But if the order is deleted, it makes no sense to remove the Customer. Having a customer with no orders is a perfectly valid state for the database.

Comment: In my case I need to delete the translation when an level is deleted. So just the other way around. But it should work anyway? Or l am wrong? And already a big thank you for your effort!

Comment: @jor I edited my answer to add more explanation. Hopefully it is now clear.

Comment: you are a beast my friend!